# Which one is correct here?

Tags: verb-usage

Which is correct: "It's a beautiful day. I ***am not taking/won't take*** the bus to work today. I prefer walking."

Comment: Which one do you think is correct?  Why would either be wrong?  We ask you to please add more information to what is confusing or difficult about this structure, otherwise the question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are perfectly correct. If you're doing homework then I'd say the second way with "won't take" is the most correct since it's probably trying to teach tenses, however in reality I'd be more likely to say the first way.

Another way to say it would be "I'm not taking the bus today since it's such a nice day out, and I prefer walking anyway."